# placeId not working as request parameter for Places Details search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I know they just deprecated id and reference, and I'm getting valid placeIds with my initial search- but for some reason when I go to search for details like this:

```
function(place_id){

    var request = {
        placeId: place_id
    }

    this.service.getDetails(request, function(data){
        //Da callback
    });
}
```

I get an error asking for the deprecated field 'reference':

```
Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify reference.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the used API-version.

The current release-version is 3.16, you must use the `reference` there

Starting with 3.17 you may (and should) use `placeId`